# Getting HTTP data in background not working

Tags: swift, xcode

Arbitrary loads are = YES and background fetch is checked in capabilities. What am I doing wrong exactly? Are there online courses that explain these concepts? This is inside the app delegate file. I want to retrieve data from a URL when the app goes into the background.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if let url = URL(string:"https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=exch_nasd,sh_curvol_o500,sh_price_u5&o=-change") {
        //url successful
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                //failed
                print("FAILED")
            } else {
                //successful
                print("SUCCESSFUL")
            }
        })
        print("TASK DID NOT RUN")
        task.resume()
    } else {
        //url failed
        print("URL FAILED")
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: its not running the task. It prints "TASK DID NOT RUN"

Comment: Did you enabled `Background Fetch` in `Background Mode` of your project `Capabilities`

Comment: You print "TASK DID NOT RUN" after creating task but before starting it. The appearance of that message has nothing to do with whether the request ran or not. That having been said, it won't continue to run this after the app enters background mode. You either need to use background `URLSession` (the most robust solution) or you need to request a little time to start and complete your request (you only have 3 minutes for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler:)` before running your code. Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623031-beginbackgroundtask). The system stops the execution of your app when entering background and you should use this function in order to obtain more time for running. Also remove "TASK DID NOT RUN". It will always be printed

This is your full code:

```
var identifier: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = 0

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

self.identifier = application.beginBackgroundTask {
  application.endBackgroundTask(self.identifier)
}

if let url = URL(string:"https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=exch_nasd,sh_curvol_o500,sh_price_u5&o=-change") {
    //url successful
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            //failed
            print("FAILED")
        } else {
            //successful
            print("SUCCESSFUL")
        }
    })

    task.resume()
} else {
    //url failed
    print("URL FAILED")
}
}
```